# Can I download an audio file and use it for push notification sound in iOS?

Tags: ios, push-notification

I want to download a file and store it somewhere in my app, for example `NSUserDefaults`, and then play it with a push notification.

Is it possible? If so, where is the best place to store this audio file?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this, but it's not so much "best place" as "only place": /Library/Sounds. [Here is the appropriate documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html)

Specifically this:

> You can assign the filename of a nonlocalized custom sound in the app’s main bundle (**or data container**) or you can assign UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName to get the default system sound.

And this:

> For remote notifications in iOS, you can specify a custom sound that iOS plays when it presents a local or remote notification for an app. The sound files can be in the main bundle of the client app **or in the Library/Sounds folder of the app’s data container**.

Comment: When receiving the remote notification, how can I change the sound of the 'default' to the ones of the library/Sound folder ? would be appreciated if you share some code.